# Excel, more efficient formula for multiple IF ANDS

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet that I am making that looks as follows:

```
Index   Diff    Exc    Sym      Sec    Result   Criteria Met

3.42    -2.07   0.86    0.92    1.83    1.95    
-0.38   -2.93   0.87    0.23    -2.01   0.09    
-2.67   -1.84   0.87    -2.49   -3.48   1.32    
-0.65   -0.98   0.46    0.98    -2.01   0.00    
-0.73   -2.79   -1.07   -2.15   -1.44   -0.10   
0.15    2.33    -0.46   -0.66   3.17    0.38    0.38
0.90    -3.68   -0.72   -1.01   -1.36   1.69    
0.68    -1.12   -0.36   0.73    -1.34   -0.29   
-1.19   -1.70   -0.56   -1.31   1.45    0.49    
-0.45   -0.69   -0.56   -1.22   0.00    -0.49   
2.94    8.38    2.21    6.25    4.96    1.74    
-1.04   7.36    2.59    3.00    2.17    2.97    
1.21    1.73    3.05    1.48    3.56    0.77    
-1.10   1.86    0.60    1.18    1.07    -0.49   
-0.89   -3.19   -1.78   -2.24   -4.26   -0.81   
-1.17   -3.44   0.11    -1.22   3.66    0.36    
0.52    0.92    -1.02   0.38    1.96    -1.40   -1.40
-0.90   3.01    -0.86   0.62    0.97    -0.50   -0.50
2.78    1.46    0.00    0.47    1.95    0.84    

        Max     Min             
Index    2.00   -2.00               
Diff    10.00   0.00                
Exc      0.00   -10.00              
Sym     10.00   -10.00              
Sec     20.00   0.00
```

Under the headings Index, Diff, Exc, Sym, Sec, Result is all data,  In the criteria met column i have a formula that checks if the prior headings fall within the Max and Min limits of the smaller table underneath, and if they do it posts the result, if they dont all fall within the Max and Min boundaries it leaves it blank. I did that by using this formula:

```
=IF(AND(A3<$B$24,A3>$C$24,B3<$B$25,B3>$C$25,C3<$B$26,C3>$C$26,D3<$B$27,D3>$C$27,E3<$B$28,E3>$C$28),F3,"")
```

copied down the criteria met column.  It works perfectly fine for what I want it to achieve but as this spreadsheet grows and I add more columns it seems like it will be incredibly inefficient and prone to alot of human error.  Is there a way to achieve the same results but by using a more efficient formula?

a picture for reference as well:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this array formula:

```
=IF(SUM((A3:E3<=TRANSPOSE($B$24:$B$28))*(A3:E3>= TRANSPOSE($C$24:$C$28)))=COLUMNS(A3:E3),F3,"")
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode. When done correctly Excel will automatically put `{}` around the formula to denote an array formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

One caveat, the Columns to be compared need to be in the same order as the min/max rows.

---

Also, as has been stated by nearly everyone if the Min Max were transposed to rows from column it would alleviate needing to use a CSE array formula.  The following would work:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A5:E5>=$A$3:$E$3)*(A5:E5<=$A$2:$E$2))=COLUMNS(A5:E5),F5,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I was hoping there would be a way where the columns wouldnt have to be in the same order using some sort of Lookup or Match function but I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: @user3524727 I also played with trying to use INDEX/MATCH but could not make it work either.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
=IF(AND(A3=MEDIAN(A3,B$24,C$24),B3=MEDIAN(B3,B$25,$C$25),C3=MEDIAN(C3,B$26,$C$26‌​),D3=MEDIAN(D3,B$27,$C$27),E3=MEDIAN(E3,B$28,$C$28)),F3,"")
```

I would also move the criteria table into a separate tab to avoid that you have to adjust the loacation of the min/max values in your formula every time you add new rows to your data table.

Comment: reread the trick here (http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/24/between-formula-excel/) you need to include the value to check in order for this to work.  So the first part would be A3=MEDIAN(A3,B24,C24), the second part would be B3=MEDIAN(B3,B$25,$C$25), so on and so forth

Comment: Correct formula is: =IF(AND(A3=MEDIAN(A3,B$24,C$24),B3=MEDIAN(B3,B$25,$C$25),C3=MEDIAN(C3,B$26,$C$26),D3=MEDIAN(D3,B$27,$C$27),E3=MEDIAN(E3,B$28,$C$28)),F3,"")

not sure on the etiquette is for editing the post...

Comment: Thanks for catching the error guys. I updated my formula.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(PRODUCT(IF(ROW>TRANSPOSE(MIN),1,0),IF(ROW<TRANSPOSE(MAX),1,0))=1,RESULT,"")
```

In this example, A11:E11 is a row of data with RESULT in F11 and the MAX and MIN criteria are in $B$27:$B$31 and $C$27:$C$31, respectively.

```
=IF(PRODUCT(IF(A11:E11>TRANSPOSE($C$27:$C$31),1,0),IF(A11:E11<TRANSPOSE($B$27:$B$31),1,0))=1,F11,"")
```

Enter the expression as an **array formula** (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER). Make sure to use a relative reference for each row of data and absolute references for the MAX and MIN criteria. Then copy/paste to evaluate other rows. Modifying this formula to accommodate additional columns of data can be done by extending the ranges.

If you are permitted to transpose the range that holds the MAX and MIN criteria to the same orientation as the data, the TRANSPOSE functions in this solution can be eliminated and the spreadsheet layout will be cleaner.

Hope that helps

Comment: The `=1` seems redundant since any non-zero is treated as TRUE.

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for. Do you think there would be a way to solve the original problem without having to keep the MAX and MIN criteria in the same order as the data table? For example I will eventually have a few hundred columns of data but I will only want to put the MAX and MIN limit on roughly 25% of them.   Ive tried using an index match or some sort of look up but it keeps failing

Comment: One idea is to group the columns that have max/min together. Another is to set up phony criteria for the 75%, e.g., min = -1000000, max = +1000000, or whatever limits will guarantee that you don't lose data. You might also explore Filters in Excel's Data Tab. Filters provide a flexible way for you to select data that meet your criteria --- and you could avoid having to design and maintain the worksheet formulas.

Comment: If you're working with a large amount of data you might also consider using a database. Selecting subsets of data based on criteria is what they're made for.

Answer (score 1):

Often in Excel, in order to simplify your formulas, you need to make your layout a little more complex. Without writing any vba, my approach would be ...
1) I would transpose your min / max layout and have them align with the columns of data.
2) Insert another sheet to hold intermediate calculations.

Here's Sheet1 ...
[image]

and here's Sheet2 ...

[image]

In Sheet2, cell B5 contains a typical formula ...

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!B5<Sheet1!B$2,Sheet1!B5>Sheet1!B$3),1,0)
```

In Sheet2, cell G5 (and down) contains ...

```
=PRODUCT(B5:F5)
```

In Sheet1, cell H5 (and down) contains ...

```
=IF(Sheet2!G5=0,"",Sheet2!G5*G5)
```

It could omit the logic and you could make the sheet settings to not display 0 values.

If you add columns (e.g. insert columns between Sheet1 column F and G):
- add Max and Min values for new columns on Sheet1
- insert the same columns on Sheet2
- drag the formula from column F on sheet2 to the new columns on Sheet2
- verify the Product formula in the "Result" column on Sheet2 contains the new columns on Sheet2.

This method helps identify exactly what caused you to fail to meet your criteria.

Comment: In the third formula there is no need to multiply in the last criterion of the IF().  A simple `=IF(Sheet2!G5=0,"",G5)` would suffice as it will either be 0 or 1