# Making Excel IF AND Statement More Efficient

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested, nested-if

I have a price list in which customers will be charged different amounts according to how many products they order and if they are an existing customer.

I am trying to write a nested IF with AND statement with the following conditions:

```
Order 1-10 and TRUE = 3*1.2
Order 1-10 and FALSE = 3
Order 11-20 and TRUE = 2*1.2
Order 11-20 and FALSE = 2
Order 21 or more and TRUE = 1*1.2
Order 21 or more and FALSE = 1
```

So far I have a formula which works but is less than elegant where B1 is the order volume, B2 is existing customer and E1/F2/F3 are the prices.

```
=IF(AND(B1<11,B2=TRUE),E1*1.2,IF(AND(B1<11,B2=FALSE),E1,IF(AND(B1<21,B2=TRUE),F1*1.2,IF(AND(B1<21,B2=FALSE),F1,IF(AND(B1>=21,B2=TRUE),G1*1.2,G1)))))
```

Is there a way to make this formula more short/efficient?

Comment: Is this MS excel?

Comment: Nobody knows what this is because you didn't add any tags...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is Excel.

Comment: May be worth looking here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/36318497/4961700

Comment: I would set up a table, and use one of the `LOOKUP` functions (eg `VLOOKUP`).

Comment: @Prezza I updated my answer below to account for the `E1`/`F2`/`F3` stuff. I missed that the first time around. Check out the final answer for something that should be a lot more light-weight.

Answer (score 4):

You could separate it out a bit like:

```
=If(B2, 1.2, 1)*If(AND(B1>=1, B1<=10), 3, If(And(B1>=11,B1<=20), 2, 1))
```

If you convert this over to math you could just do:

```
=If(B2, 1.2, 1)*ROUND(30/CEILING(B1, 10), 0)
```

Or:

```
=(1+B2*0.2)*ROUND(30/CEILING(B1, 10), 0)
```

That's getting a little silly though.

---

Updated for the `E1`/`F2`/`F3` difference. I didn't catch that the first time around. I think the following would be the way to go (kind of a mix of option 1 and option 3 above).

```
=(1+B2*0.2)*If(B1<=10),E1,If(B1<=20), F2, F3))
```

I think the biggest gain is seperating out the logic to determine your multiplier (`1.2` vs `1` depending on `B1`) and the logic for determining the price (your `If` statement and `E1`/`F2`/`F3`)

Comment: Your final offer is elegant +1